# Django - TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-queryset

I was trying add paginator to my website using some online code but I'm getting this error
return len(self.object_list)
TypeError: object of type 'method' has no len()

**Views.py**

> def sample(request):

> ```
>     WAllPAPER_PER_PAGE = 2
>     wallpapers = Wallpaper.objects.all
> page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
> wallpaper_paginator = Paginator(wallpapers, WAllPAPER_PER_PAGE)
> try:
>     wallpapers = wallpaper_paginator.page(page)
> except EmptyPage:
>     wallpapers = wallpaper_paginator.page(wallpaper_paginator.num_pages)
> except:
>     wallpapers = wallpaper_paginator.page(WAllPAPER_PER_PAGE)
> context = {"wallpapers": wallpapers, 'page_obj': wallpapers, 'is_paginated': True, 'paginator': wallpaper_paginator}
> return render(request, "Wallpaper/sample.html", context )
> ```

**Models.py**

```
class Wallpaper(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    pub_date = models.DateField('date published', null=True)
    resolution = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tags)
    Device_Choices = [
        ('PC', 'pc'),
        ('mobile', 'mobile')
    ]
    Devices = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=Device_Choices, default= 'PC')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='Wallpaper/Images/', default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *call* `.all()`, otherwise it is a reference to a method, so you work with:

```
#                     call .all() ↓↓
wallpapers = Wallpaper.objects.all()
```

The reason that you need to call this is because the `Paginator` expects something that is iterable and has a length, like a list or a `QuerySet`.