# return bool field in django view set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I wanna return boolean field of a model in view set but I have an error

model:

```
class AdviceRequests(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="user_advice_requests")
    ADVICE_REQUESTS = (
        ('Yes', 'yes'),
        ('No', 'no'),
    )
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
        default='+989121111111', null=False, blank=False)
    advice_requests = models.CharField(
        choices=ADVICE_REQUESTS,
        default='YES',
        max_length=10)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

my view:

```
class AdviceRequestsActiveView(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = AdviceRequestsSerializer

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        advice_req = AdviceRequests.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        active = advice_req.active
        print(active)
        return active
```

I have a question when my user come to my site like do you need advice?
after that I have a boolean field named active,when user answer the question no matter is yes or no

the field be True like we asked this user before don't ask again
now I wanna return this field in the view.

Error is:`object of type 'bool' has no len()`

Comment: may be the issue is in the template? Could you please put the part of your template the the question?

Comment: I just do back end code, in post man don't return anything

Comment: ok got it, could you please add more detailed error trace, bc based on current part of code it doesn't looks relevant error

Comment: active field is boolean field and I try to return it all error is : return len(self.object_list)
TypeError: object of type 'bool' has no len()

Comment: What your expectation of the call the `len(True)` or `len(False)`?

Comment: no I just to try return that to know I asked question from the user or not,if didnt ask ask question,if asked dont ask again,I tried with boolean field that name is active

Comment: There is a bigger problem here: You are using `get_query_set` method from the view to do something it is not supposed to do. That function is supposed to return a `queryset`. That is why the error is `object of type 'bool' has no len()`. Because the one calling it is specting it to have `len()`. I encourage you to read more about views and serializers on DRF. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/

Comment: yes you are right ,at first I did wrong

Answer (score -1):

you can update your method with this:
the main issue: you use **AdviceRequests.objects.get** and at the same time you inherit from **ListModelMixin**

you need to use *.all()* or *.filter()*

or

you need to in inherit from another class to retrive one obj

and try this

```
 def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
     advice_req = AdviceRequests.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
     active = advice_req.active
     data = { "active": active }
     return Response(data, status=200)
```

Comment: object of type 'Response' has no len()
 now return this error from bool to Response

Comment: the main issue: you use **AdviceRequests.objects.get** and at the same time you inherit from **ListModelMixin**

Comment: @AshtiNematian you can check my answer, I have updated it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70127446/django-typeerror-object-of-type-method-has-no-len 
here is the same issue, check the answer there